# How to count number of methods in java

Tags: java

I am trying to count the numbers of methods in .Txt file ,this file is written in `java`

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fichiertext.txt"));
        try {
            Method[] sd = br.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            System.out.println(sd);
```

Comment: You would need to compile, load that file using classloader and then use the way you did above. If you are just interested in method names from a text file then use regex and search for method names.

Comment: Java is not regular, therefore, @SMA's suggestion to regexp through it will not work.

Comment: As rzwitserloot mentions, you'll need a Java parser. This is easily solved using an Antlr parser generated for Java9.g4, a simple XPath eval on the CST to find the methods (or a simple custom tree walker), and a count of the size of the result list--maybe a dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for the declared methods of the `BufferedReader` definition itself. That's why what you wrote doesn't work, and the idea behind what you wrote never will.

Java, the runtime, has no idea what java (source code) is, whatsoever. There is nothing in the API that lets you do this.

Both of @SMA's suggestions also do not work. Their first suggestion is that you take the code, run it through a java compiler (which any given java virtual machine run may or may not have - `JavaCompiler` is a class in java, you can use that to compile things, but it may return `null` to indicate no compiler is available). However, even if one is available, **this will not work**:

To fully compile a source file, you need all its dependencies. And yet, to count methods, you don't need to know any of that. If a method refers to, say, `ImmutableList`, then you can still count that as: Yup. 1 method. Even if you have no idea what `ImmutableList` might be referring to. Whereas a full compile run can't get the job done unless it knows.

Furthermore, once compiled, the strategy you have so far would involve loading in the compiled result so that you can then invoke `.getDeclaredMethods`. Don't do that - loading in classes will initialize them. If the static initializer of a class hangs, throws an exception, or formats the disk, then either you end up not having a Class object to invoke `.getDeclaredMethods()` on, or worse, you get your disk formatted.

So, you do *NOT* want to compile the source file, and you do *NOT* want to initialize the resulting class file even if you managed to compile it.

SMA's second suggestion involves regular expressions. This is dumb advice - regular expressions aren't magic. They can parse regular grammars. Java grammar isn't regular, so, no can do.

So, what *do* you do?

It's not easy.

What you need is a java parser: A thing that understands java grammars. Parsers, as a first general step, take a bunch of text and turn that into a so-called 'AST': An abstract Syntax Tree. It's a tree structure: Such a library returns a `CompilationUnit` object, which has `.getPackage()` for the package statement, `List<ImportStatement> getImports()` for the imports, and then `List<TypeDefinitions> getTypeDefs()` for the type definitions, which is usually 1 (you can put multiple classes in one .java file, as long as only one is `public`). That would in turn have methods to ask for all the inner classes, fields, initializers, constructors, and methods included, and so on.

An AST is (or does not need to be) 'linked' - it can just say that e.g. the class `extends FooBar`, leaving `FooBar` as a string, without letting you ask about what FooBar's stuff contains. This is good, because it means it is possible to make this step even if you do not have FooBar.java.

With an AST you can just write code that loops through and counts whatever you want to count.

To obtain an AST you need a java parser. You have 3 major options:

- javac - you can't really use any built-in compiler for this, it's not public API. It's also GPL licensed, so unless you also GPL your code, you can't legally do this. The API is not public, in the sense that it can change in later versions. Hence, not recommended.
- ecj - the compiler of the eclipse project. It has a permissive open source license, is fast, and very accurate. However, the API is not easy to use, because it's been with us for 20 years, and is optimized for speed. A good choice.
- Some other parser. There are a bunch of parser libraries out there for java, most permissively licensed, and many include a java grammar as a proof of concept and as an example to show how the parser works and that it is capable of parsing something very complicated, like java. The compatibility of such grammar tools is usually lacking (there are exotic java features they don't support, or they get certain things wrong), but they are usually *far* easier to use.

All 3 of these involve pulling in dependencies and are, for an experienced programmer with absolutely no experience whatsoever with parsers, on the order of a personweek of work.

For a junior java programmer, hoo boy. Tricky stuff. Multiple weeks.